# How to line-break an HTML list on last possible white space

Tags: html, css, whitespace, word-wrap, line-breaks

I have a simple HTML list:

```html
<ul>
  <li>First Item</li>
  <li>Second Item</li>
  <li>Third Item</li>
</ul>
```

I want to display the list with the following features:

1. Items in a row.
2. List would have a maximum width, after which items are expected to break to the next line.
3. Items should only break on beginning / spaces (not mid-word).
4. Lines should contain the most text possible before breaking.

**Desired outcome:**

```
[   maximum width   ]
First Item * Second
Item * Third Item
```

**Failed attempts:**

*#1 (word breaks)*

```
[   maximum width   ]
First Item * Second I
tem * Third Item
```

*#2 (item doesn't break properly)*

```
[   maximum width   ]
First Item * Second Item
* Third Item
```

*#3 (line breaks "prematurely")*

```
[   maximum width   ]
First
Item * Second Item *
Third Item
```

**Update:**
A simple `li {display: inline;}` won't work if the HTML is not indented / spaced (some frameworks -- say, GatsbyJS -- automatically "squeeze" the HTML):

```
<ul><li>First Item</li><li>Second Item</li><li>Third Item</li></ul>
```

[(Fiddle example)](https://jsfiddle.net/8puLkcry/)

Comment: `li {display:inline}` should be enough

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```css
ul {
    max-width: 100px;
}
ul li {
    display: inline;
}
ul li::after {
  content:" ";
}
```

Why the `after` part?

Well, unless there is a white-space / new-line after each `<li>` in the HTML **source**, the line won't break at the end of items, which may very well cause a "premature" line-break (as in the failed attempt #3). Some frameworks automatically "squeeze" the HTML -- basically removing these white-spaces -- and this requires an explicit space to be added after each item.

[Here's a Fiddle examples](https://jsfiddle.net/gwadzxuc/) (try removing the `after` from the `css` and see how you get failed attempt #3).

Answer (score 1):

As Temani already said `li {display: inline;}` works fine. ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr214kvs/2/))

Comment: This seems to work fine with plain HTML, but doesn't work for me with GatsbyJS (getting #3). I've noticed that with the gatsby version, the first item (which has 2 white-spaces and breaks prematurely) has one less glyph in the rendered fonts view (Dev tools -> Elements -> Styles -> Computed -> Rendered fonts). What could this mean? Perhaps something with my environment? My gatsby server is running via WSL.

Comment: OK that's not GatsbyJS per se. This won't work when the HTML is not indented: https://jsfiddle.net/8puLkcry/